# Unknown Database while Database does exist in phpMyAdmin (XAMPP)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a database for my platform in order to safe user information such as usernames, e-mail addresses and passwords. I recently installed XAMPP on my device and changed all port statements in the documents `my.ini`, `httpd.conf`, `php.ini`, and `config.inc.php` to 3307 since I already had MySQL running on port 3306 through MySQL Workbench. I created a database called ***useraccounts*** ([img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNZUU.png)) on the server with port 3307 and made a php file with the database name, the user, and the password as follows:

```
<?php
  $db_user = "root";
  $db_pass = "";
  $db_name = "useraccounts";

  $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=" . $db_name . ";charset=utf8", $db_user, $db_pass);
  $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::EERMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

At first, when I didn't give in any password, it gave an error telling me I needed a password. When I filled in the password for the root user from MySQL Workbench, I got the following message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'useraccounts' in C:\xampp\htdocs\useraccounts\Config.php:7 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\useraccounts\Config.php(7): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', '4.UruZ$fnw!ZMH5') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\useraccounts\Registration.php(2): require_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\useraccounts\Config.php on line 7
```

I'm not sure how to solve this. Does anyone know if there might be a cross over between my servers on port 3306 and 3307 or that there might be another problem or way to solve it?

Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: You could try: `"mysql:host=localhost;port=3307;dbname="`. That is, add the port number in the Data Source Name. No idea if it will work...

Answer (score 0):

By default, PHP will use port 3306 unless you specify a different one. You will need to add `port=3307;` to your connection string.

```
<?php
  $db_user = "root";
  $db_pass = "";
  $db_name = "useraccounts";

  $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;port=3307;dbname=" . $db_name . ";charset=utf8", $db_user, $db_pass);
  $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::EERMODE_EXCEPTION);
```